# What are ways to unit test Rest API clients - i.e. testing that the right Rest requests are sent

Tags: scala, scalatest, akka-http

At work we're developing a service that sits between two other services. We expose a Rest API which is called by some service -- the request is processed by some logic and then, according to the logic, HTTP requests will be sent out another service.

There're plenty of resources on the internet on how to best test API endpoints you provide. I, on the other hand want to test what API requests are sent out, without sending them to the actual service.

I guess I could always set up an entire server skeleton on localhost:8080 that just records what it receives but this feels kinda dirty. Testing the Rest API we provide for external services (we use akka-http to do that) is pretty comfortable to test with akka-http-testkit which is excellent. I was just wondering if there is any comparably comfortable to use tooling to test what Http reqeusts go out.

Answer (score 1):

**Functional Programming "Tooling"**

The easiest way I've found to test these scenarios is to use plain-old functional programming principles in your design.  You can embed your `Route` creation within a higher order function.  This higher order function will take in the function which queries the downstream service:

```
type ComputedData = ???

val computeData : HttpRequest => ComputedData = ???

def intermediateRoute(downstreamService : ComputedData => Future[HttpResponse]) : Route = 
  extractRequest { request =>
    val computedData : ComputedData = computeData(request)

    complete(downstreamService(computedData))
  }
```

This higher order function can now be used in Production:

```
val queryDownStreamService : ComputedData => Future[HttpResponse] = ???

val productionRoute : Route = intermediateRoute(queryDownStreamService)
```

Or, it can be used in unit-testing to ensure the logic is correct:

```
val testComputedData : ComputedData => Boolean = ???

val testResponse : HttpResponse = ???

val testService : ComputedData => Future[HttpResponse] = (computedData) => {
  assert(testComputedData(computedData))

  Success(testResponse)
}

val testRoute = intermediateRoute(testService)

Get("/test") ~> testRoute ~> check {
  response should be testResponse
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We do it the way you call `dirty`, though I don't think it's `dirty`.

we have a base trait that starts/shuts down the server (we use http4s and scalatest)

```
trait EmbeddedServer extends BeforeAndAfterAll with Http4sDsl[IO] {
  self: Suite =>

  private var server: Server[IO] = _

  protected var lastRequest: Request[IO] = _

  private def captureRequest: HttpService[IO] = Kleisli { req: Request[IO] =>
    lastRequest = req
    service(req)
  }

  override protected def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    server = BlazeBuilder[IO]
      .bindAny()
      .mountService(captureRequest, "/")
      .start
      .unsafeRunSync()
    super.beforeAll()
  }

  override protected def afterAll(): Unit = {
    super.afterAll()
    server.shutdownNow()
  }

  def address: InetSocketAddress = server.address

  def rootURI: String = s"http:/$address"

  def service: HttpService[IO]

}
```

then we mix it in our `client` spec

something along these lines

```
class SomeRequesterSpec extends WordSpec with EmbeddedServer {

  override def service: HttpService[IO] = HttpService[IO] {
    case GET -> Root / "failure" => ServiceUnavailable()
    case GET -> Root / "success" => Ok(SuccessBody)
    case GET -> Root / "partial-success" => Ok(PartialSuccessBody)
    case GET -> Root / "malformed" => Ok(MalformedBody)
    case GET -> Root / "empty" => Ok(EmptyResponse)
  }

  //... you specs go here

}
```

and in you specs you call your `mocked` server with your client
using `s"$rootURI/success"` or `s"$rootURI/failure"` endpoints and check that it handles responses correctly.
Also `lastRequest` var always has last request  issues, so you can run assertions against it, like

```
lastRequest.headers should contain(`Accept-Encoding`(ContentCoding.gzip))
```

This approach works very well for us and we can test that our clients handle all sorts of outputs from servers as well as all manipulations with request they do